# Floating-point efficiency of Python library function implementations

Tags: python, performance, implementation

I've seen various answers to the ball collision detection question explaining why sqrt operations are slow, why absolute value operations are fast on floating ponts etc. How can I find out which operations are expensive and which are not?

Basically, I'm looking for a resource where I can learn about the implementation of all the python library functions. When people are saying those things they aren't actually thinking about how that stuff is implemented in C are they?

Thanks, looking to learn more about implementation details on this slick language.

Comment: I think you're asking **specifically about floating-point functions/subroutines**, not algorithmic efficiency (e.g. don't take sqrt when not necessary, just compare squared-distances directly), big-O or bytecode in general? *"looking for a resource... about the implementation of all the python library functions"* is way too general. Also, the bytecode compiler is getting improvements every version, as of 2024 the current release is 3.12; see the whatsnew. As to optimizations of floating-point esp. for 2D/3D games, there are tons of discussions on that since the 1970s, see those.

Comment: e.g. for collision detection, bounding-boxes in 3D were developed to use octrees as  a data structure that can quickly be searched. There's about half a century of literature on that, going back to C and assembler. See also e.g. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collision-detection . Always look first for high-level algorithmic and data-structure optimizations like octrees, not low-level stuff.

Comment: One legendary eighties compilation of efficient F-P algorithms for graphics is the ["Graphics Gems"](https://www.realtimerendering.com/resources/GraphicsGems/) series of books, free PDFs and repo online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is, like any language, translated to machine code and then run. So yes, they could be talking about low-level implementation details.

Anyway, the best way to learn about speed implementation of the various Python functions is [taking a look in the source code.](http://www.python.org/download/source/)

Have fun!

EDIT: This tip actually applies to any open source project I worked with: Got a problem? Take a look at the source code and you should be fine.

Comment: Ok so I downloaded the source code and unzipped it. Now I have a folder called Python-3.1.2 and it is confusing! Any tips on sifting through the source and finding what I'm really looking for? Thanks

Comment: I took a quick look on the source, and if my guesses are correct, the source file you should take a look at cmathmodule.c. There is a function called c_sqrt that does the job of finding the square root, and it is written in C. So, it really comes down to the implementation of sqrt in C after all.

Answer (score 2):

You find out which operations are slow and which ones are fast by using the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module.

For example, let's compare the various methods of checking if a point falls within a circle, from the command line:

```
python -m timeit -s 'import math; x = 42.5; y = 17.2; r = 50.0' 'math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2) <= r'
python -m timeit -s 'import math; x = 42.5; y = 17.2; r = 50.0' 'math.hypot(x, y) <= r'
python -m timeit -s 'import math; x = 42.5; y = 17.2; r = 50.0' 'x**2 + y**2 <= r**2'
```

On my machine the results are:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'import math; x = 42.5; y = 17.2; r = 50.0' 'math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2) <= r'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.744 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'import math; x = 42.5; y = 17.2; r = 50.0' 'math.hypot(x, y) <= r'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.374 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'import math; x = 42.5; y = 17.2; r = 50.0' 'x**2 + y**2 <= r**2'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.724 usec per loop
```

so `math.hypot` wins!  Incidentally, if you remove the dotted name lookup from the inner loop, you get slightly better results:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'from math import hypot; x = 42.5; y = 17.2; r = 50.0' 'hypot(x, y) <= r'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.334 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for tips on Python speed in general, [these performance tips](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips) are a good resource.

Comment: 90% of the stuff in that article only applies to ~Python2.1 (that was 8 years ago) and is just plain false for todays Python implementation. It can show you how much Python improved, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

The Python standard library includes [a disassembler](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html):

```
>>> def foo(): print
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  1           0 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              1 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              4 RETURN_VALUE
```

It doesn't work on everything, though:

```
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(sqrt)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dis.py", line 48, in dis
    type(x).__name__
TypeError: don't know how to disassemble builtin_function_or_method objects
```